# Halt the mouse wheel on keyboard key down

Tags: xorg, mouse, scrolling

I have a Synaptics trackpad (specifically a BCM5974) on a MacBook5,1.

If I lift my fingers off of my trackpad after scrolling without deliberately pausing the scroll motion first, the scroll will drift for a while. This itself is not a problem, and in some cases is a pleasant way to read.

However, in Chrome (and in other situations) preparing to use a key combination like Control-1 to switch to my first open tab results in undesired Control-Scroll behavior, because Chrome sees the scrolling events while I'm holding down the Control key.

In a perfect world, I'd like to halt deceleration on the receipt of a key down event from my keyboard. Obviously there will still be cases where I'd like to scroll while holding a key, so *I don't want to disable the scroll wheel behavior* when I press a key. I just want to *halt* the deceleration that may already be in progress.

I'm aware of `synclient` for controlling my trackpad, and I already use it to adjust other parameters like sensitivity and speed. I'm not seeing a way to influence the motion in progress, however.

My distro is Gentoo, and as such is essentially custom. I'm using Xorg 1.18.0 with Fluxbox.

(I'm specifically avoiding the use of the word "stop" here, because Google searches for "stop scroll wheel" or "stop trackpad scroll" uses "stop" in the same notional sense as "disable".)